# Uppercase a specific column in multy table SELECT (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show a specific column all in uppercase, but I can´t do while selecting multiples tables. Thanks for your help.

**table_1**

id - name - last_name

**table_2**

id - person_id - amount

SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2, UPPER(table_1.name) WHERE table_1.id = table_2.person_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected columns go first (that tables)

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*, UPPER(table_1.name) as nameUpper FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.id = table_2.person_id
```

Comment: It works, but only shows that column, is there a way to also show the other columns while keeping that one in uppercase?